# Which is faster string searching or regex searching?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have been given a SQL file in which more than one stored procedures are there. For a given table name, I have to find a Procedure name in which that table is used. This can be done by using `split()` method and  string searching. 
If I use regex searching, will it be more efficient to extract the procedure names?

The searching will be done in a multiple file inside a directory of size in GB's.
For eg: I have been given a SQL file in which two stored proc are there and I need to search a proc name in which the table `ucg2.userCompanyId` is used.

```
USE [BI]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ActiveUsersAM_prc]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[ActiveUsersAM_prc]

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[ActiveUsersAM_prc]    
--ActiveUsers_getdata_prc    
    @Usercompanyid varchar(max)    
AS     
Begin    


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ActiveUserCompany') IS NOT NULL  
DROP TABLE #ActiveUserCompany  

CREATE TABLE #ActiveUserCompany  
(userCompanyId INT)  

INSERT INTO #ActiveUserCompany  
SELECT val FROM dbautil.dbo.Split_fn(@userCompanyID,',')  


CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_usercompanyId ON #ActiveUserCompany(userCompanyId)  

SELECT * FROM dbo.ActiveUsersAMCache_tbl (nolock)
WHERE userCompanyId IN (SELECT userCompanyId FROM #ActiveUserCompany (nolock))

END  

USE [BI]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ActiveUsersRelatedCompanies_prc]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[ActiveUsersRelatedCompanies_prc]

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[ActiveUsersRelatedCompanies_prc]  
    @Usercompanyid INT
AS     
Begin  

select * 
FROM dbo.ActiveUsersRelatedCompanies_tbl (NOLOCK)
WHERE userCompanyId in (
        select  ucg2.userCompanyId
        from    userCompanyGrouping_tbl u
                inner join userCompanyGrouping_tbl ucg2
                    on isNull(u.subParentCompanyId,u.parentCompanyId) = 
                        (case when u.subParentCompanyId is not null then ucg2.subParentCompanyId 
                            else ucg2.parentCompanyId end)
        where   u.userCompanyId = @userCompanyID
)       
order by userCompanyName, userGroup, fullName
END
```

In it how to use regex searching for extracting procedure name for a given table name and will it be faster than string searching?

Comment: Depends on the regex. Depends on the string. Depends on your machine. Best would be for you to measure it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj  example is added

Answer (score 4):

Does it really matter which one is going to be more efficient? Any difference will be on the order of microseconds. Your bigger problem is just figuring out a way that works. If that turns out to be too slow, then figure out a way to make it faster. Your concern with efficiency before you have a working approach is a classic case of premature optimization.

Whereas you can *probably* come up with a regular expression that will do what you want, doing so will be very difficult unless you're very well versed in regular expressions. Using `string.Split`, on the other hand, is very easy to implement and you can have working code in a few minutes. And it will likely be quite fast enough for your purposes.

Do yourself a favor: opt for the simple solution and move on. Save the optimization efforts for things that really matter.

Comment: "any difference will be on the order of microseconds." Actually, it can vary much more than a few microseconds.

Comment: @fabigler The searching needs to be done on a multiple files inside a directory of size in GB

Comment: @rishabh: If it's being done on multiple files inside a directory, then your limiting factor will be file I/O. It will take hundreds of milliseconds to open and read each file. The time it takes to search the data once you load it in memory will be insignificant in comparison. You're optimizing the wrong thing.